# Is there an equivalent of c++ union with int and string member variables in c#?

Tags: c#, c++

In c++ we can use same address for string and int variables through use of unions. I am looking to define a union in c# which has two member variables of type int and string.

I have tried 3 ways to define union in which two those shown below work, but they dont look exact equivalent to union of c++. Third one which seems like equivalent of union shows error "Application is in break mode"

This works but doesn't seem like its equivalent of c++ union, as addresses consecutive of integers stay same while that of strings change. (One pair of int and string must have same address in case of a union).

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 128)]
public struct File_element
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int Line_no;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public string Line;
}
```

This works too but I have to define two objects instead of a single, still not sure its equivalent of a union of c++ though

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 128)]
public struct File_element
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int Line_no;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct File_element2
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
    public string Line;
}
```

What I am looking for which I think will be exact equivalent of c++ unions will be this one, but this shows an error ("Application is in break mode") when I try to run

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 128)]
public struct File_element
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int Line_no;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public string Line;
}
```

Error which I see is "Application is in break mode"

Comment: In the last case both members reside at the same address but the first is value type while the second is reference type. Reference types are prepended with header of 2 words size, which is messed up with content of `Line_No` and which breaks the application.

Comment: What do you mean by `string in C++`? Is it a pointer or a `std::string`?

Comment: Kinda pointless to not mention the exception.  But no, the CLR will not allow this.  It breaks the garbage collector, it cannot know whether the string is referenced.  Only fixed-size buffer can work, surely what you'd really want to map a char[] in the C++ code.

Comment: Just as a sidenote: Unless you explicitly need this, you shouldn't "think" in C++ when writing C#/.Net Code. If in C++ do things the C++ way, if in C# do things the C# way. You are just shooting your foot over and over again if you mix them up.

Comment: @SGKoishi I have no where mentioned this

Comment: @HansPassant 3 times I mentioned exception "Application is in break mode" in my question

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public unsafe struct File_element
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int Line_no;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public fixed byte Line[128];
}
```

Equal to

```
union File_element
{
    int Line_no;
    char Line[128];
}
```

You can use `Line` field like a normal array:

```
unsafe
{
    File_element f = new File_element();
    f.Line_no = 0x060708;
    Console.WriteLine(f.Line[0]); //8
    Console.WriteLine(f.Line[1]); //7
    Console.WriteLine(f.Line[2]); //6
}
```

You can also add a property to convert `Line` to string

```
public unsafe struct File_element
{
    ....

    public string LineString
    {
        get 
        {       
            fixed (byte* p = Line)      
                return new string((sbyte*)p);
        }
    }
}

f.Line_no = 0x373635;
Console.WriteLine(f.LineString); //567
```

Comment: can u add set to your code along with get too? I want to try your code, but I see error "property or indexer cannot be assigned to, it is read only". I want to give string input to f.LineString